# what is the execution mechanism of the setInterval function

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I want to know, How it works the `setInterval` function.

**First:** I have simple example ([Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gGYKV/4/))
Also the code below.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="elem"></div>
<div id="count"></div>
<div id="Timer"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var s = 10;
var count = 0;
if (s == 20) alert("S= 20");
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (count < 50) {
        count++;
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = "Counter: " + count;
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(timer);
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = "Counter: End Of Count";
    }
}, 50);
s = 20;
document.getElementById('elem').innerHTML = "variable 's': " + s;
document.getElementById('Timer').innerHTML = "Timer value: " + timer;
if (s == 20) alert("S= 20");
```

All I want is how the function it works.
After implement the code of function , is it return to the beginning of code at top page , or return to implement the function code again until use clearInterval function.

Anybody help me please.

Comment: As in you want to know how the underlying javascript engine is programmed for this function? Or simply what the function is and how it works? Your question isn't very clear..

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setInterval

Comment: When enter the function, is continue to implement the code until the timer is finished then get out, or every time enter the function and out and so on

Comment: is this means that Do enter once  to implement the code and then go out, or enter and out more than once to implement the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are supplying an anonymous function to `setTimeout`.

The anonymous function supplied to [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) is called  **asynchronously**. The anonymous function cannot run for the first time until the current function is complete.  The call to `setInterval(function() {...})` is *registering* your anonymous function for execution every 50ms; it does *not* execute immediately.

Your program flow runs like this:

```
set initial variables
check if s == 20
register (not execute) the anonymous function with setInterval
set s = 20
print results
check if s == 20
end of your code blcok
...
50ms later, the first call to your anonymous setTimeout function finally happens
Repeatedly call the anonymous function every 50ms
```

**Takeaway point:** If you need certain operations to happen after the anonymous function completes, put those operations inside the anonymous function itself.  In your code, I suspect you want some lines that currently come after the `setTimeout` call and place them inside the `else` block in your anonymous function.

Comment: **Great, that's what I want, thanks for help**, but I have two mini questions about same subject. **(1-** if we add a normal function like `setInterval(function,100)`, is follows the same execution approach of anonymous functions. **(2-** How can I make sure that the timer(`setInterval`) has been stopped or cleared after using `clearInterval` function.

Comment: 1. Correct, it doesn't matter if the function is named or anonymous, they will behave the same.  2. I don't quite understand what you're asking here.  You seem to be using `clearInterval` correctly.  Are you asking how to check if some interval has been cleared (e.g., by something like `isIntervalCleared`)?  There is no such function, I'm afraid -- you'll have to track that in your program yourself.

Comment: Thanks for help again, and I'm sorry if I bother you.

Comment: Not at all -- glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval keeps calling the enclosed function repeatedly till clearinterval is called. the delay can be given in seconds 1000 = 1 sec, since you have given a small delay of 50 the function is called repeatedly in quick succession till it reaches the 50 limit

Comment: When enter the function, is continue to implement the code until the timer is finished then get out, or every time enter the function and out and so on

Comment: is this means that Do enter once  to implement the code and then go out, or enter and out more than once to implement the code

Comment: im unclear on what you are asking above, the whole page starts loading and if the delay is reached before the whole page loads, setinterval starts executing the enclosed function. so if the page is taking awhile to load and your delay has passed it starts executing the function and keeps executing till clearinterval is called

Comment: I'm sorry, I know my question is not clear, but I hope you understand me.
As you know in the javascript loop, when enter the loop continue to implement the code does not go out until after the completion of the number of iterations.
my question is: is `setInterval` function Follow this approach like loops continue to implement the code does not go out until after use `clearInterval` function.

Comment: Yes, (using your code above) setInterval continues to execute the function every 50ms until clearinterval is called.  OR till the window/page is closed or redirected.

Comment: good, but if you see my code again, the value of variable `s` is Printed and the value of `timer` also is Printed, and their code after the timer code, consequently,Supposed to not be printed until after call `clearInterval` function to get out from timer function to complement the rest of the code .